# Why does two different input to this scanf() gives two diffrent outputs?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,m;
    scanf("%d : %d",&n,&m);
    cout<<n<<m;
}
```

Why does input given 1 2 gives an output 10 while input 1:2 gives output 12.

Comment: Does `1 2` match `"%d :%d"`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide an [mcve]. Describing code is not a good idea, details matter.

Comment: *different inputs* giving *different outputs* ?

Comment: You should check the return value of the `scanf` call, to see how many values were *actually* read.

Comment: You need to check the return value of scanf to see how many patterns matched and stored data -- patterns that weren't reached due to earlier match failures won't store anything in the corresponding argument, leaving it uninitialized.

Comment: cannot reproduce. `1:2` gives output `12` (as expected), not `10`.

Comment: I am a beginner can you please explain what checking the return value of scanf means?

Comment: Here is some documentation about [`std::scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf).  It's not *official*, but the website is pretty good about being up to date and accurate (and quickly fixes problems brought to their attention).

Comment: The format string `"%d : %d"` tells `scanf()` to expect there is input that can be interpreted as two integral values separated by a colon (and whitespace).  If the input doesn't include the colon, `scanf()` stops reading immediately, and doesn't attempt to read the second value.   So input `1 2`  will read the `1`,  discard the space, not find a `:` and immediately stop, leaving the `2` waiting to be read.   Since `scanf()` has read only one of the two expected values, it returns `1`  (whereas it would return `2` if it had succeeded in reading two values, such as with the input `1:2`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running different samples of code based on your description. I found, `scanf("%d :%d")` will listen to the input of the user and when an input of type `(value1:value2)` supplied `:` will be used as delimiter. Whereas if you do not supply an input with `:` it will simply select the initial value and assign a `GARBAGE` value to the later one.

You can use different characters such as `/` in place of `:` and it will work in the same manner.

Comment: "and assign a GARBAGE value"; actually not; it will not assign anything to `m` but let it unchanged (uninitialized in this case)

Comment: If input is supplied without the `:` then `scanf()` does not modify the second variable at all.   The "garbage value" you're seeing - like the OP's code - is because your code never initialised the variables.   Not modifying an uninitialised variable leaves it uninitialised.   Then printing it accesses that value - causing undefined behaviour, and one possible symptom of undefined behaviour is "garbage" output.

Comment: Uninitialized values are not garbage. Anything can happen if you read them. You're not guaranteed to get a random value, or any value at all.

Comment: Kindly refrain from starting answers with thanking the OP for asking, and ending them with "*hope this helps*" - it does not make any sense. Please see the [community guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258187/is-it-ok-to-write-hope-that-helps-or-why-is-my-answer-being-edited) on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` reads in (and assigns) only so far as the input matches the provided format. All other parameters (i.e. those that do not match) remain unchanged. The return value of `scanf` is the number of items that matched (and got assigned).

To illustrate this, see the following program. I am using `sscanf` and passing the arguments in form of a string rather than user input; but the outcome is the same as if you used `scanf` and entered the values in the console:

```
int main()
{
    int n=0,m=0;
    int itemsScanned = 0;

    itemsScanned = sscanf("1:2","%d : %d",&n,&m);
    std::cout << "items scanned: " << itemsScanned << "; n: " << n << "; m: " << m << std::endl;

    n=0;m=0;  // reset...
    itemsScanned = sscanf("1 2","%d : %d",&n,&m);
    std::cout << "items scanned: " << itemsScanned << "; n: " << n << "; m: " << m << std::endl;

}
```

Output:

```
items scanned: 2; n: 1; m: 2
items scanned: 1; n: 1; m: 0
```